# How to get the width and height of a View?

Tags: react-native

I am creating a QR code, the QR lib requires for the size to be a number. I want to work with percentages so it will be responsive. So in the size of the QR I would like to put Width of the view that surrounds it 0.9. So I need to get the width of the view that surrounds it. How can I do so?

I have tried onLayout but It does not work and I see in this article:

https://cmichel.io/how-to-get-the-size-of-a-react-native-view-dynamically that is not working since two years ago.

Thanks!

Comment: What is happening with onLayout? why shouldn't it work?

Comment: Did you try Dimensions? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions

Comment: What happens when you give percantage based values to width? like this `style={{ width: "90%"}} `